# Roslaunch include file remotely

Tags: ros

I am trying to launch a file from remote computer but I could not success. Actually I can connect to remote computer but I think the problem is with including a file from remote computer. In other words, I am looking for a machine tag for include. Here is the my code:

```
<launch>  

    <group >
      <machine name="marvin-1" address="tek-marvin-1" user="blabla" password="blabla" env-loader="/home/blabla/.rosLaunchScript.sh"/>  

      <include file="$(find openni_launch_marvin)/launch/kinect_left.launch"/>
    </group>     

</launch>
```

Comment: You may find help on this topic here, but you may have more luck getting a fast answer at answers.ros.org.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to first ssh into the remote computer. In the remote terminal, run

```
export MASTER_URI = http://IP_address_master:Port_number
```

where `IP_address_master` should be the IP address of the computer on which you want to run the master node. IP address could either be of your local machine or remote computer. `Port_number` is the port of your master node (generally it is `11311`). On the same terminal, run

```
export ROS_IP = IP_address_remote
```

where `IP_address_remote` is the IP of your remote computer.
In the terminal of your local machine (not the one where you are running ssh from), run the following commands:

```
export MASTER_URI = http://IP_address_master:Port_number
export ROS_IP = IP_address_local
```

where, `IP_address_master` and `Port_number` is same as above but `IP_address_local` should be the IP address of your local computer.

Now, you are ready to launch the file from your remote terminal. Your no longer require a separate launch file. In the ssh terminal, run the launch file `kinect_left.launch` directly as:

```
roslaunch openni_launch_marvin kinect_left.launch
```

Answer (score 0):

The following hacky method is only valid if you have packages / launch files that are ONLY available on remote.  If the packages / launch files are available on both host and remote machine, you can simply use the `<machine>` tag from roslaunch which is much cleaner.

(cross posting from https://answers.ros.org/question/371480/roslaunch-nodes-launch-files-only-available-on-remote-machine/?answer=371491#post-id-371491)

Assuming host has ssh key access to remote, I accomplished this with the following:

Host machine launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="local_pkg" type="remote_bringup.sh" name="remote_bringup"/>
</launch>
```

Host machine `remote_bringup.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'ssh remote@remote "pkill roslaunch"' INT TERM
ssh remote@remote "~/bringup.sh"
wait
```

Remote machine `bringup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/install/setup.bash
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://host_machine:11311
export ROS_IP=remote_machine
nohup roslaunch remote_pkg normal.launch &
```

The script properly catches SIGINT, SIGTERM and forwards it to the remote machine's `roslaunch`